# MySQL SQL syntax error near '0' at line 1

Tags: mysql, string, stored-procedures, where-clause, concatenation

I have tried various modifications to make this work but I can't seem to remove the error. My SQLQuery string is much larger than the one below but same set up. I tried using a `CONCAT(' ')` statement but had issues. So I tried using this format but still receive the same error. any suggestions?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `stp_Select_GetTbl`(IN strWhereClause 
VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE SQLQuery varchar(1000); 

SET SQLQuery = '
SELECT `Part Num` AS `PPNumber`,
`Shop Num` as `SOrder`
FROM `track`.`s list` WHERE ';

SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + strWhereClause + '';

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLQuery;
EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

ERROR:

```
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1
```

`
I have tried not declaring SQLQuery... changing varchar size... reorganizing and even using the example below

```
SET @getList =
CONCAT('SELECT (t1, t2, t3) FROM (SELECT t1, t2, t3) as mainSelect WHERE ', strWhereClause, '');

PREPARE stmt FROM @getList;
EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

but get error at 
    `.... MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0`

I need to define a string for my SELECT statement because I create the WHERE clause in my stored procedure.

Comment: 1st - don't use spaces in names associated with tables or column names as you will cause all sorts of issues.  2nd can you show the full SQL it's trying to execute? (i.e. what is the 'strWhereClause' value)

Comment: The spaces are there because the initial developer had spaces in original names and etc. I also can't show the full SQL statement as it is confidential. However, these smaller versions should still work but they don't. I will modify my example to remove spaces for the `AS ` section. However, with a smaller version it should be enough but I still have issues. A WHERE clause example would be like `SOrder='11222'` @NigelRen

Comment: "The spaces are there because the initial developer had spaces in original names"  This is one of many reasons to create a view instead of accessing the table.

Comment: the original code was a view but I am moving it to a stored procedure without a view and then we are converting to SQL server. So for now I have to try and use this set up. I've used a CONCAT string before and it worked fine so I am unsure why this is causing me issues @ChrisCaviness

Comment: You also should test strWhereClause for empty or null or your prepare will fail.